# Java Native Library for Windows 7, printf

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I'm trying to build a java native library for Windows 7 using gcc.
I get it to compile and build.

As a test I'm just trying to do `printf()` in the native code.

```
gcc -o Test.so -shared -O -I/home/fred/jdk1.8.0_65/include -I/home/fred/jdk1.8.0_65/include/linux Test.c
```

In Test.c:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Test_print(JNIEnv *env, jobject jo) {
    printf("Test\n");
}
```

when run it does not return from the printf().

If I remove the printf() Java_Test_print() returns.

If I replace the printf() with while (1) {}
it hangs as expected.

I know it gets to my native code but it doesn't return from the `printf()` and crashes the JVM.

ldd on the dll shows that it is using `/usr/bin/cygwin1.dll`.

I suspect there's a problem with calling conventions.  Even if that's the case, I'm not what do to do about it.

Has anyone successfully developed a native library for Windows? Or have any pointers. Thanks!

Comment: did you include `stdio.h` ? have you any warnings?

Answer (score 0):

```
   Step 1:

   Test.c:
   #include <jni.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Test_print(JNIEnv *env, jobject jo) {
      printf("Test\n");
      return;
    }

   Step 2:
    Build .dll file
    gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include" -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" -shared -o Test.dll Test.c

   Step 3:
    public class Test {
    public native void print();
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("Test");
         }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException { 
      Test test = new Test();
              test.print();
     }
  }
```

**Reference Link** : https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html